# Spock Integration Test interaction not counted

Tags: grails, testing, integration-testing, spock

I want to write an integration test for my Grails User Class.

I have a `afterUpdate()`method which calls the afterUpdate method in the userService which calls another service.

Now I want to verify that the call to the other service is done correctly. If I debug the code, the method is called correctly. but my test always fails and says the method isn't called:

```
    def "After Update for User"() {
        given:
        RedisService.metaClass.'static'.del = {String key -> true}
        User user = new User()
        user.save(flush: true)

        when:
        user.afterUpdate()

        then:
        1 * redisService.del(!null)
    }
```

I have tried different things like

```
then:
1 * user.userService.afterUpdate(!null)
1 * userService.redisService.del(!null)
1 * redisService.del(!null)
```

but they are all failing.

I allways get:

```
| Failure:  After Update for User(com.boxcryptor.server.RedisCacheIntegrationSpec)
|  Too few invocations for:

1 * user.userService.afterUpdate(!null)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None

Too few invocations for:

1 * redisService.del(!null)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

**Update:**

the after Update Method is really simple:

```
def afterUpdate(User user) {
    deleteETagCache(user)
}

def deleteETagCache(User user) {
    redisService.del(user.id.toString())
}
```

Comment: could you integrate the question with the code of the `afterUpdate`?

Comment: It's not possible to check interaction without using Mock() or Spy().

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing overriding methods with metaClass magic and mocking a class or an object. I would try:

```
def "After Update for User"() {
    given:
        def redisService = Mock(RedisService)
    and:
        User user = new User()
        user.save(flush: true)
    and:
        user.redisService = redisService

    when:
        user.afterUpdate()

    then:
        1 * redisService.del(user.id.toString())
}
```

Also, I would create as a unit test, not as an integration test.